# Cloning URL from DevOps Repository in SourceTree

Tags: git, azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree

I am a Mac User. And I'd like to clone my repository of azure `DevOps` to local using source tree.

What I did is,

1. opening SourceTree
2. `Remote` > Click `Clone` of the repository I want to clone in the list of Azure DevOps

And I get this window.

[image]

The `Source URL` is

> https://ORG_NAME@dev.azure.com/ORG_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/_git/REPOSITORY_NAME

When I click `This is not a valid source path / URL`, It says,

```
real URL is https://spsprodea1.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?
...abort: 'https://ORG_NAME@dev.azure.com/ORG_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/_git/REPOSITORY_NAME' does not appear to be an hg repository:
---%<--- (text/html; charset=utf-8)


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">




<html lang="en-US">
<head><title>

            Azure DevOps Services | Sign In

</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;&#32;IE=10;&#32;IE=9;&#32;IE=8" />
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico"/>
...

---%<---
!
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://ORG_NAME@dev.azure.com/ORG_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/_git/REPOSITORY_NAME' 
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://ORG_NAME@dev.azure.com/ORG_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/_git/REPOSITORY_NAME' 
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://ORG_NAME@dev.azure.com/ORG_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/_git/REPOSITORY_NAME' 
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://ORG_NAME@dev.azure.com/ORG_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/_git/REPOSITORY_NAME'
```

I already added my DevOps account to SourceTree using `username` and `PAT` without any problems.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if SourceTree is using its embedded Git version, or your own "System" Git.
[SRCTREEWIN-9456](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-9456) and [SRCTREEWIN-9312](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-9312) reported issues with Git 2.19.1 and GCM ([Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows))

If your `git config credential.helper` is set to manager (the Windows Credential Manager), check if the issue persists when using the [latest Git 2.22 Git for Windows release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

Comment: I am using Mac. What should I do in this case? `git config credential.helper` shows `osxkeychain`

Comment: @c-an Same issue: check if what version of Git you are using, then check if you have credentials cached for ORGNAME.

Comment: The git version is `git version 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)`. And How can I check if I have credentials cached for ORGNAME?

Comment: @c-an You can follow https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain to check if you have a `dev.azure.com` entry with `ORGNAME` in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try erasing the ORG_NAME from the url and also the '@' , it must look like: https://dev.azure.com/ORG_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/_git/REPOSITORY_NAME

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try change git config credential.helper to sourcetree instead osxkeychain:

```
git config credential.helper sourcetree
```